# Perfect forwarding of functions to build a function list class

Tags: c++, function, c++11, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following code that build a class storing functions.

```
// Function list class
template <class... F>
struct function_list
{
    template <class... G>
    constexpr function_list(G&&... g) noexcept
    : _f{std::forward<G>(g)...}
    {
    }
    std::tuple</* F... OR F&&... */> _f;
};

// Function list maker
template <class... F, class R = /* Can we compute the return type here? */>
constexpr R make_function_list(F&&... f)
{
    return function_list<
        /* decltype(std::forward<F>(f))...
         * OR F...
         * OR F&&...
        */>(std::forward<F>(f)...);
}
```

I would like these functions to be perfectly forwarded (regardless of whether they are function pointers, functors, lambdas...). But I don't exactly understand all the type deduction happening behind `std::forward` and universal references. In the code above, I have three questions:

- Should `_f` be of type `std::tuple<F...>` or `std::tuple<F&&...>` (and why?)
- Is it possible to deduce the return type `R` in the template parameter list (because doing it manually instead of `auto/decltype(auto)` would be helpful to understand what is going on)
- In the maker, what the `function_list` template argument should be: `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)...)`, `F`, or `F&&...` (and why?)

Note: the constructor of `function_list` is not meant to be called directly, instead `make_function_list` is doing the job.

EDIT:
Is this case safe, when the `operator()` of `function_list` (not shown here) is not guaranted to be called on the same statement?

```
template <class... F>
constexpr function_list<F...> make_function_list(F&&... f)
{
    return function_list<F&&...>(std::forward<F>(f)...);
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly would **not** want them to be `F&&`.

Comment: 1) `tuple<F...>` 2) You wouldn't need `R` in the template list, you already know the return type is `function_list<F...>` 3)  `F&&` because it is a forwarding reference that binds both to rvalue and lvalue refs (you said you wanted perfect forwarding, so this is how you'd get it)

Comment: if you can guarantee that the function call operator is invoked within the same statement as `make_function_list`, you can use `F&&` (you can express that using a ref qualifier, `&&`, on `operator()`)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: when you say "you can use `F&&`, which bullet point are you refering: 1) 2) and 3)?

Comment: @Vincent the 1st one. you don't need to repeat `&&` in `std::forward`

Comment: @Vincent If this question is in reference to the previous question, I checked and it is perfectly forwarded. I'm only unsure if the class is optimized completely away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't exactly understand all the type deduction happening behind `std::forward` and universal references.

It's quite simple to understand via an example.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&&)
{
    std::tuple<T>{}; // (0)
    std::tuple<T&&>{}; // (1)
}
```

In the case of **(0)**:

- `T` is deduced as `T` for *rvalues*
- `T` is deduced as `T&` for *lvalues*.

In the case of **(1)**:

- `T` is deduced as `T&&` for *rvalues*
- `T` is deduced as `T&` for *lvalues*.

As you can see, the only difference between two is how *rvalues* are deduced.

Regarding `std::forward`, this is what it does:

```
template <typename T>
void g(T&&);

template <typename T>
void f(T&& x)
{
    g(x) // (0)
    g(std::forward<T>(x)); // (1)
}
```

In the case of **(0)**:

- `x` is always an *lvalue*.

In the case of **(1)**:

- `x` is casted to `T&&` if `T` is deduced as `T`.
- `x` stays an *lvalue* otherwise.

`std::forward` basically retains the type category of `x` by looking at how `T` was deduced.

---

> Should _f be of type `std::tuple<F...>` or `std::tuple<F&&...>`

I think that in your case it should be `std::tuple<F...>`, as you want to store either **lvalue references** or **values**.

`std::tuple<F&&...>` would store either **lvalue references** or **rvalue references** - that would lead to *dangling references* in the case of temporaries.

---

> Is it possible to deduce the return type `R` in the template parameter list

Yes, it is just `function_list<F...>`.

```
template <class... F, class R = function_list<F...>>
constexpr R make_function_list(F&&... f)
{
    return function_list<F...>(std::forward<F>(f)...);
}
```

You don't even need the `R` template parameter.

```
template <class... F>
constexpr function_list<F...> make_function_list(F&&... f)
{
    return function_list<F...>(std::forward<F>(f)...);
}
```

---

> In the maker, what the `function_list` template argument should be: `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)...)`, `F`, or `F&&...`

`function_list` should take `F...` as a template parameter for the reasons listed at the beginning of this answer *(i.e. avoiding dangling references to temporaries)*.

It should still take `std::forward<F>(f)...` as its arguments to allow *rvalues* to be forwarded as such *(i.e. moving rvalues into `function_list`'s tuple)*.

Answer (score 2):

If they are `F&&`, then if you pass a temporary to `make_function_list`, the returned class containing a `tuple` will store an rvalue reference to the temporary passed to `make_function_list`.

On the next line, it is now a dangling reference.

This seems bad in most use cases.  This is not actually bad in *all* use cases; `forward_as_tuple` does this.  But such use cases are *not* general use cases.  The pattern is extremely brittle and dangerous.

In general, if you are returning a `T&&`, you want to return it as a `T`.  This can cause a copy of the object; but the alternative is danging-reference-hell.

This gives us:

```
template<class... Fs>
struct function_list {
  template<class... Gs>
  explicit constexpr function_list(Gs&&... gs) noexcept
    : fs(std::forward<Gs>(gs)...)
  {}
  std::tuple<Fs...> fs;
};
template<class... Fs, class R = function_list<Fs...>>
constexpr R make_function_list(Fs&&... fs) {
  return R(std::forward<Fs>(fs)...);
}
```

Also make `function_list`'s ctor `explicit`, because in the 1 argument case it devolves to a rather greedy implicit conversion constructor.  This can be fixed but takes more effort than it is worth.

`operator()` requires an instance.  A type name is not an instance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `function_list` is for. There basically are two cases:

1. `function_list` is a temporary helper that should never outlive the statement it appears in. Here we can store references to functions and perfect-forward each of them to the point of invocation:

   ```
   template <class... F>
   struct function_list
   {
       std::tuple<F&&...> f_;

       // no need to make this template
       constexpr function_list(F&&... f) noexcept
           : f_{std::forward<F>(f)...}
       {}

       template <std::size_t i, typename... A>
       decltype(auto) call_at(A&&... a)
       {
           return std::invoke(std::get<i>(f_), std::forward<A>(a)...);
       }
   };
   ```
2. `function_list` is a wrapper/container object akin to `std::bind`, in this case you'd want to store decayed copies of the functions to avoid dangling references and perfect-forwarding in this context would mean forwarding functions to the constructors of their decayed versions in `f_` and then at the point of call imbuing the decayed functions with value category of the `function_list` itself:

   ```
   template <class... F>
   struct function_list
   {
       std::tuple<std::decay_t<F>...> f_;

       template <typename... G>
       constexpr function_list(G&&... g)
           : f_{std::forward<G>(g)...}
       {}

       template <std::size_t i, typename... A>
       decltype(auto) call_at(A&&... a) &
       {
           return std::invoke(std::get<i>(f_), std::forward<A>(a)...);
       }

       template <std::size_t i, typename... A>
       decltype(auto) call_at(A&&... a) const&
       {
           return std::invoke(std::get<i>(f_), std::forward<A>(a)...);
       }

       template <std::size_t i, typename... A>
       decltype(auto) call_at(A&&... a) &&
       {
           return std::invoke(std::get<i>(std::move(f_)), std::forward<A>(a)...);
       }

       template <std::size_t i, typename... A>
       decltype(auto) call_at(A&&... a) const&&
       {
           return std::invoke(std::get<i>(std::move(f_)), std::forward<A>(a)...);
       }
   };
   ```

   As with `std::bind` if you actually want to store a reference, you must do so explicitly with `std::reference_wrapper`.

Construction is the same in both cases:

```
template <class... F>
constexpr auto make_function_list(F&&... f)
{
    return function_list<F...>(std::forward<F>(f)...);
}
```